# Static SQL conditional WHERE clause from a Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

say i have the following function:

```
function xx_func 
return varchar2
is

    l_value varchar2(1);

begin

    select  'Y'
    into    l_value
    from    func_table
    where   lookup = 'hello';
    
    RETURN l_value;
    
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        l_value := 'N';
        RETURN l_value;
end xx_func;
```

Now, in the current PL/SQL code, we have this:

```
DECLARE

    l_optin varchar2(100);
    t_col1  varchar2(100);

BEGIN

    l_optin := xx_func;
    
    if l_optin = 'Y' then
    
        select  col1
        into    t_col1
        from    xx_table_1 xx1
            ,   xx_table_2 xx2
        where   1=1
        and     xx1.t_col2 = xx2.t_col2;
        
    else

        select  col1
        into    t_col1
        from    xx_table_1 xx1
            ,   xx_table_2 xx2
        where   1=1
        and     xx1.t_col2 = xx2.t_col2
        and     xx1.t_col3 = xx2.t_col3;
        
    end if;
    
END;
```

I wanted to code it like this to make it shorter:

```
DECLARE

    l_optin varchar2(100);
    t_col1  varchar2(100);

BEGIN

    l_optin := xx_func;
    
    select  col1
    into    t_col1
    from    xx_table_1 xx1
        ,   xx_table_2 xx2
    where   1=1
    and     xx1.t_col2 = xx2.t_col2 
    and     ((xx1.t_col3 = xx2.t_col3 and l_optin = 'N')
    OR       (l_optin = 'Y'));
            
END;
```

The code above tells me `If l_optin is 'N'` then `evaluate xx1.t_col3 = xx2.t_col3. if l_optin = 'Y'`, then don't evaluate `xx1.t_col3 = xx2.t_col3.`
I tried testing it locally and it works but my co-worker says it won't work on all scenarios. The columns are not nullable.

Are there any possible scenarios that this wouldn't handle?

Note:

- We cannot use Dynamic SQL
- this sample code occurs multiple times in the package of over 14000
  lines, hence, it's quite hard to read at that point.

Comment: From my point of view, as you aren't charged by number of characters you type, use option which is easier to follow and maintain. First code you posted is simple - if function returns Y, do *this*; otherwise, do *that*. Your second code looks *smarter*, but - is it more efficient? Imagine someone who inherits your code. Imagine *yourself* inheriting a) simple code, b) complex code. Which one would you prefer? I'm not saying that this example is *that* complex; it's just that I prefer having it simple.

Comment: Ask your co-worker for scenarios where it wouldn't work, because there aren't any as far as I am concerned (none that also wouldn't work for the original query at least. If you want to make the code shorter, I question the use of `1=1` as part of the `WHERE` clause, AFAIK that's only useful if you are already using dynamic SQL and need to ensure a valid where clause to append to.

Comment: Also if we are talking about style and readability, the `OR` in the second version is misleadingly placed and inconsistently capitalised.

Comment: @Littlefoot When someone has to come along and clean up that comma join, would they prefer to edit one query or two? :)

Comment: I agree with Connor. I have started writing answer recommending usage of ANSI joins and breaking up logic of `xx_func` function into single SQL 
(i.e. `... from xx_table_1 xx1 join xx_table_2 xx2 on xx1.t_col2 = xx2.t_col2 left join func_table ft on ft.lookup = 'hello' where (ft.lookup is not null or xx1.t_col3 = xx2.t_col3)`).
Anyway I finally consider its readability disputable - the ANSI syntax is suitable for join chains of two tables at a time, here we actually have three tables, all involved in join condition in one go - and from performance point of view it is not clear winner too.

Comment: @Littlefoot sorry i didn't clarify. this sample code occurs multiple times in the package of over 14000 lines, hence, it's quite hard to read at that point.

Answer (score 2):

For every person that argues for a SQL statement per requirement (ie, 2 statements above) there will be a person that argues for getting as much "bang for your buck" out of a single SQL (1 statement above), so I'm not going to try tell you which is right or wrong.

My *preference* is generally multiple statements because I'm giving the optimizer the best chance at a good plan, but there is no rule, because 2 statements might be fine, but 200 sounds like I've taken things too far etc.

Similarly, the two are not mutually exclusive - I've seen code where there are multiple permutations possible and thus the most common usages are coded in static SQL with a "fallthrough" option being dynamically built SQL for the rare permutations.

You pick what *you* are comfortable with, whilst meeting the goals of maintainability and keeping things simple for the optimizer.

Whilst I assume your examples are pseudo-code, just in case they are indeed representative of your real code

- you don't need "where 1=1"
- if the "col2" join yields a single row, how can "col2/col3" pairing yield anything different?